# Simple javascript wouldnt excute | First Javascript write up | Changing Text Color

Tags: javascript

first time coding java script, I don't quite understand why this simple code wouldn't work with my HTML page. does this syntax looks wrong?

'changecolor' is a 'span id element' in my HTML - its working when i change it with CSS but not with the js below

```
var txt = document.getElementById('changecolor');

    txt.style.color = "red";
```

I tried calling it as a function, and still nothing

```
var txt = document.getElementById('changecolor');

function changeColor(){

    txt.style.color = "red";


}

changeColor();
```

I'm 6 hours in learning javascript... and im already lost

Comment: Can you add also your html code and where you put your Javascript code?

Comment: You need to put this code after `<span id="changecolor"> ..... </span>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code is correct. You can see example below.

```js
var txt = document.getElementById('changecolor');

function changeColor(){
    txt.style.color = "red";
}

changeColor();
```

```html
<span id='changecolor'>TEST</span>
```

The problem is that you probably insert JavaScript code before your HTML tags. You should include Javascript at the end of file or wrap everything with ready function.

```
DomReady.ready(function() {
    var txt = document.getElementById('changecolor');
    txt.style.color = "red";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, as you said, when i placed the JavaScript code before the span tag instead of in the head section it worked! - wasn't expecting this out come at all - i clearly have to do more research on js, thank you once again Tajni!

Answer (score 0):

have you thought about linking your JS script to HTML, we can solve your problem with the following code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html> 
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf 8">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script> <!-- LINK JS -->
      <title>Title</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
     <p id="txt" onclick="changeColor()">Click me to change my text color.</p>
  </body>
```

```
function changeColor(){
  document.getElementById("txt").style.color = "blue";
}
```

Comment: Thank for sharing Valenin Cadart, but it seem this is exactly why it didnt work? - doesnt make much sense to me so i have to look into to is for - maybe DOMReady.ready(function) will give me a hint